# C# write graph to coordinate-system

Tags: c#, .net, sql, coordinate-systems

There are millions of data in my SQL DB and every Row is a Item with a Starttime and a duration. Now I want to visualize this Data to know which Data overlap at a time.

My idea is to create a coordinate-system with x-axis show the time and y-axis count the Item. Every graph is a line parallel to the x-axis start at Starttime + duration. The next graph is y+1 and also Starttime + Duration. Then I can see which Items overlap at which time.

How can I program that with C# any suggestion to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Can you draw your idea for better understanding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should take a look in the various chart controls out there:

- [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489065.aspx)
- [Dundas](http://www.dundas.com/)
- [Nevron](http://www.nevron.com/)
- *whatever you find on the net*

All of these support some kind of bar chart which could visualize this kind of data. But be aware that displaying can take a lot of time if you try to put millions of data points at a chart at once.

If high performance and mass of data is your constraint you should maybe take a look at one of these:

- [Lightning Chart](http://www.arction.com/)
- [Measurement Studio](http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/4807)
- [Dynamic Data Display](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/)
- *whatever you find on the net*

Comment: thx for your answer, is any Framework optimized for high performance?